# SSO with OAuth for Communities

Tags: single-sign-on

Is it possible in Salesforce to provide a link on VF in the Customer portal so that once the portal user logged in and clicks on that link they should be redirected to the Community Home Page?

Comment: yes you can redirect user from one page to another page or tab but user should have access for that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its entirely possible and well documented. Here are several links you may find useful. [Getting Started With Communities](http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf) (See Security & Authentication), [Best Practices for Implementing Single Sign-On](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_tips.htm&language=en_US) and [Single Sign-On for Customer Portal Users](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000002855&type=1).